# How to Order By on a key inside JSONB column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, jsonb

I want to get all the details for a particular userID in DESC order of email_subject which is a key present inside "metadata" column of type JSONB.

Metadata is a JSONB column which has below structure:

```
{
 "emails" : [ {"recipients":["userId1@testsite.com"], "email_subject":"Test Subject1"},
              {"recipients":["userId2@testsite.com"], "email_subject":"Test Subject2"}]

}
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM details
WHERE classification = 'EMAIL'
AND EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM jsonb_array_elements(metadata->'emails') x 
            WHERE x->>'recipients' LIKE ('["%userId1@testsite.com%"]') ORDER BY x->>'email_subject' DESC)
            ORDER BY metadata->'emails'->>'email_subject' DESC
```

The above query is able to give me required results for userId "userId1@testsite.com" but I want the final result to be sorted as per this field :

metadata->'emails'->>'email_subject'

I would appreciate all the inputs/suggestions.

Comment: Hi, just to make sure: please add the exact expected result from your data sample

Comment: With your example data, that only returns one row, so ordering it doesn't make sense.  Maybe you want to return the results of jsonb_array_elements, rather than just testing it.